# Run Github Action after Google Cloud build trigger is complete

Tags: github-actions, google-cloud-build

I would like to run my automation tests Github Action (already working) when my Google Cloud Build job finishes.

My Google Cloud Build job has a name (`build-and-deploy-dev`), so I thought I would add it as a requirement to my automation test Github Action .yml file.. but clearly, I am not doing it right - I am pretty new to Github Actions.

I have attached my current Github Actions (you can see, there is a `build-and-deploy-dev` which builds and deploys the app to app engine) and there is an `End-to-end tests` Github action which runs on: push but I would like to run it right after the build/deploy is done.

Thanks[image]

[image]

Comment: Please copy/paste YAML instead of screenshots, that makes it easier to search. Also, what error message do you get on the end-to-end tests? (please copy those as text -- not as screenshot)

Comment: @penguinsource did you find any solution here ?